# using data.table to create sequence from starting points and increments

Tags: r, data.table, sequence, cumulative-sum

I would like to use data.table to repeatedly add an increment to a starting point.

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(time=seq(from=as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 01:00:01"),to=as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 01:00:10"), by="secs"), int=c(2,3,3,1,10,10,10,10,10,10), x=2*1:10)

> dat
                  time inc  x
 1: 2018-01-01 01:00:01   2  2
 2: 2018-01-01 01:00:02   3  4
 3: 2018-01-01 01:00:03   3  6
 4: 2018-01-01 01:00:04   1  8
 5: 2018-01-01 01:00:05  10 10
 6: 2018-01-01 01:00:06  10 12
 7: 2018-01-01 01:00:07  10 14
 8: 2018-01-01 01:00:08  10 16
 9: 2018-01-01 01:00:09  10 18
10: 2018-01-01 01:00:10  10 20
```

That is, starting in row 1, I would like to add the value of `inc` to `time`, yielding a new time. I then need to add the value of `inc` at that new time, to arrive at a third time. The result would then be

```
> res
                  time inc  x
1: 2018-01-01 01:00:00   2  2
2: 2018-01-01 01:00:02   3  6
3: 2018-01-01 01:00:05  10 12
```

I would probably know how to do this in a loop, but I wonder whether data.table can handle these sorts of problems as well.

Since the values in `time` are continuous, my ideas was to use the cumulative values of `inc` to index, along the lines of

```
index <- dat[...,cumsum(...inc...),...]
dat[index]
```

but I cannot get `cumsum()` to ignore the values in between the points of interest. Perhaps this can be done in the `i` part of data.table but I would not know how. Anyone an idea?

Comment: You may need to specify the `i` for subsetting the rows.  It is also better to show your method in the post just to understand the issue better

Comment: Isn't this the same as [this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766676/data-table-and-shifts-of-varying-length)

Comment: @bumblebee if it is a duplicate post, please delete either one of the posts.  the time frame of posting both is within a day and the old post have some more info regarding the calculation.

Comment: Yes, it is the same because I felt I had a better way of explaining the issue. Sometimes I find it hard to describe the problem and post it with different descriptions. I then delete the old ones.

Comment: @akrun I specified my approach now and It hink the  `i` part is exactly the key of my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
# start with finding the next time
dat[, next.time := time + int][!dat, on = .(next.time = time), next.time := NA]

# do this in a loop for the actual problem, and stop when final column is all NA
dat[dat, on = .(next.time = time), t1 := i.next.time]
dat[dat, on = .(t1 = time), t2 := i.next.time]

dat
#                   time int  x           next.time                  t1   t2
# 1: 2018-01-01 01:00:01   2  2 2018-01-01 01:00:03 2018-01-01 01:00:06 <NA>
# 2: 2018-01-01 01:00:02   3  4 2018-01-01 01:00:05                <NA> <NA>
# 3: 2018-01-01 01:00:03   3  6 2018-01-01 01:00:06                <NA> <NA>
# 4: 2018-01-01 01:00:04   1  8 2018-01-01 01:00:05                <NA> <NA>
# 5: 2018-01-01 01:00:05  10 10                <NA>                <NA> <NA>
# 6: 2018-01-01 01:00:06  10 12                <NA>                <NA> <NA>
# 7: 2018-01-01 01:00:07  10 14                <NA>                <NA> <NA>
# 8: 2018-01-01 01:00:08  10 16                <NA>                <NA> <NA>
# 9: 2018-01-01 01:00:09  10 18                <NA>                <NA> <NA>
#10: 2018-01-01 01:00:10  10 20                <NA>                <NA> <NA>
```